# "Syntax error: Missing semicolon" in TypeScript when using "as const" syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax-error

Here is the code I used on my **react** project

```
export const animation = {
  WAVES: "waves",
  PULSE: "pulse",
} as const;

export type Animation = typeof animation[keyof typeof animation];
```

And this is the screenshot of error when I run the project
[image]

Comment: This code is fine, you need to add reproducible code.

Comment: reproducible code? how?

Comment: Pretty sure you aren't compiling your TypeScript code...

Comment: @kelly what do you mean?

Comment: what do you use to run your code?

Comment: Be sure to have TypeScript 3.4 or greater, as [const assertions were introduced in that version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Comment: I use "react-scripts start" to run the project, and the version of typescript is "^4.82"

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact version available in your environment? What is the version in your package-lock.json (or equivalent)? Can you run a `tsc -v` from a package.json script, or from yarn (e.g. `yarn tsc -v`)? Also, are you sure you're using `tsc` and not, say, Babel (e.g. `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript`) to transpile TS code?

Comment: Also, take a look at https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9800

Comment: @FlávioLisbôa I'm sure, that's the exact version of TypeScript

Comment: @SteveGerrad this version does not exist. Perhaps you mean 4.8.2? Also, due to the nature of this error, I'm almost sure you're using Babel instead, ie. transpilation is **not** done by `tsc` (which is the CLI tool that comes with the package `typescript` and transpiles your TS files into JS).

Answer (score -3):

I believe if you remove `as const;` on line 6 and replace it with just a `;` that should fix your issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Drew. `as const` add a special meaning in TypeScript, removing it will not give the expected result.

Comment: If I remove as const; it gives me another error (Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "]" ) on this line "export type Animation = typeof animation[keyof typeof animation];"

Comment: If `as const` is removed, the typing for `animation` will differ. This is not the solution, and even worse, it'll change the API surface for that module. I believe OP is just using a really old version of TypeScript. (Either that, or `as const` doesn't play well with `export`, which I find improbable).